# Changing parent element's class or style

Tags: functions, jquery

I added this bit of code to my header.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $('div').hasClass('icheckbox') && $('div').hasClass('disabled') ) {
        $('div').parent().addClass('hide_empty');
    }
});
</script>
```

My goal is to add the class .hide_empty to the parent of all div elements that have a class .icheckbox AND a class .disabled, in that order, with no other classes. The parent of these div elements is a li element in all cases.

I checked many answers to related questions and tried many variations, but whatever cariation I use, the class .hide_empty is never added to the parent li element.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks to the input of both @Andrea and @dhirenpatel22 I came up with the following working code:

In my `footer.php` I added:

```
<?php 
    function hide_empty_terms() { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
                jQuery(".icheckbox.disabled").each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('hide_empty');
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'hide_empty_terms');
?>
```

right before `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`.
This actually adds the class `hide_empty` to the parent `li` element of `<div class="icheckbox disabled">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, the  elements should be changed into `<div class="icheckbox disabled hide_empty" style="">`

that's different from the goal stated in the question where you say you want to add class "hide_empty" to the parent `<li>` of the `<div class="icheckbox">`. The code posted by @dhirenpatel22 should work to add class hide_empty to the li element, of course if the element you want to add class to is the same div it should be 
`$(this).addClass('hide_empty')`

Also note that hasClass() will return true even if the element has more classes.
To find only the divs with both and exclusively icheckbox + disabled I guess the best way is:

```
$(".icheckbox, .disabled").each(function(){
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('hide_empty');
  // or $(this).addClass('hide_empty') 
  //if it's the <div> instead of <li> you want to apply the rule
})
```

Comment: You're quite right @Andrea. I stand corrected. The HTML should be changed into `<li class="term_1675 hide_empty">`, `<li class="term_1676 hide_empty">`, etc. Thanks for your suggestion though. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thanks again @dhirenpatel22 and @Andrea, but it still doesn't work. I put an alert in, just to see if anything is processed at all, but the alert doesn't show. I'm starting to think something's wrong with the placement of the code. I put mine in `header.php`, just before the `</head>` tag. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you look at the js console? You may have js error.. Replace the instances of $ with `jQuery`

Comment: I had looked at the js console before and still no warnings or errors. Replacing `$` with `jQuery` didn't change anything, I'm afraid. I hope you have another suggestion. If not, well, I guess it's a quirk somewhere that I need to smooth out at some point...

Comment: are you on the right file? in the html source can you see yor code?

Comment: Yes, when I view the page source, the code is right there in the header section. I just tried to change a different `li` element on the page in the same way, but that didn't change either. It's as if the complete page is drawn only after the execution of the script has ended. Then again, I still don't see any alert either...

Comment: try in footer.. no idea why it does not alert if the code is in right place. can you screenshot the source code in that point?

Comment: It works! Your last remark about trying it in the footer set me on the right track @Andrea. I'll answer my own question with the complete code. Thanks to you and to dhirenpatel22 as well. I appreciate both your input!

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation hasn't reached 15 points yet. I upvoted both your answers, but it doesn't show yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated your code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
        if( $(this).hasClass('icheckbox') && $(this).hasClass('disabled') ) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('hide_empty');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this works..!!

Comment: Thanks @dhirenpatel22, but I'm afraid it still doesn't work. Should I use `$(document).ready(function()` or rather `$(window).load(function()` for the function to load after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: It would be good if you share the complete code here or provide the reference URL (if its ok with you), so that can provide a precise solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi @dhirenpatel22, I just added the html code in a comment to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the html code I aim to change:

`<div class="html_list">
    <ul class="list_checkbox">
        <li class="term_1675 ">
            <div class="icheckbox disabled" style="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="term_1675" class="checkbox_term checkbox_term_1675" data-tax="product_tag" name="advies" data-term-id="1675" value="1675" style="">
                <ins class="iCheck-helper" style=""></ins>
            </div>
            ...some more code...
        </li>
        <li class="term_1676 ">
            <div class="icheckbox disabled" style="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="term_1676" class="checkbox_term checkbox_term_1676" data-tax="product_tag" name="coaching" data-term-id="1676" value="1676" style="">
                <ins class="iCheck-helper" style=""></ins>
            </div>
            ...some more code...
        </li>
        ...etc...
    </ul>
</div>`

So, the `<div>` elements should be changed into `<div class="icheckbox disabled hide_empty" style="">`